# move an array into mysql table with one field having different values without normalising

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have an array like

```
 [cat2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34
                    [1] => 48
                    [2] => 49
                    [3] => 46
                )
```

I want to move this to a particular field to a table called shops in a column "category"

That means the first field of column category should have 34,48,49,46

So, for every id I want all the arrays to move into category column. Please help me as I am struck in middle. Thanks.

cat2 contains the array

```
$result= implode(",", $cat2);
    $rowids = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM shops ORDER BY id");
    if  ($rowids) {
    foreach ($result as $cat) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowids);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $upd = mysql_query("UPDATE shops SET categories = $cat WHERE id = $id");
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - are you saying that for every `id` in table `shops`, the value of `categories` should be `34, 48, 49, 46`?

Comment: no, for id=1 , value of category should be 34,48,49,46

Comment: What do you mean the value changes as id changes?

Comment: when id=2, cat2=3,3,31,2

Comment: Could you include the code which updates `$cat2` in your question?

Comment: array_push($cat2,$cat_ids[$x]); $shop['cat2'] = $cat2;

Answer (score 0):

use serialized 
and store in category field
example 
$array = array( "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor" );
$serialized = serialize($array);

Comment: Here you can put all category ids into a single field
it also saves memory